# Entity Framwork IsStoreGeneratedComputed false even though column mapping specifies HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)

Tags: entity-framework

I've got a column mapped using the fluent API as

```
 Property(_ => _.Designation)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

In the corresponding migration, a UDF is defined and the table is altered to map the column to the custom UDF.

But when I interrogate the metadata for this field, I see `edmProperty.IsStoreGeneratedComputed == false`.  This is surprising; I thought that `IsStoreGeneratedComputed` would be true.

At any rate, I would like to know how to detect via Entity Framework metadata that the column/field is in fact computed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public static bool IsComputed(this EdmProperty edmProperty) {
    //Note the attribute may be set to Computed even though edmProperty.IsStoreGeneratedComputed == false
    var storeGeneratedPatternAttribute = edmProperty.MetadataProperties.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Name == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern");
    return storeGeneratedPatternAttribute != null && storeGeneratedPatternAttribute.Value.ToString() == "Computed";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that the `EdmProperty` you are looking at came from C-space, not S-space. Since it's from C-space it represents the entity property, which could be scalar or a complex property. If you map it you can get the S-space `EdmProperty` which actually represents the storage column in the database and *that* would have `IsStoreGeneratedComputed == true`, just as you would have expected.

Here are [really good instructions from Rowan Miller](http://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/) on how to map between properties and columns.

However, the information *can* be extracted from C-space scalar `EdmProperties` without mapping, though it's less robust:

```
// Alternative, allows you to compare `== Identity`, `== Computed`, `!= None`, etc:
public static StoreGeneratedPattern GetSSpaceScalarColumnStoreGeneratedPattern(this EdmProperty property)
{
    MetadataProperty item;
    return property.MetadataProperties.TryGetValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern", false, out item)
        ? (StoreGeneratedPattern)Enum.Parse(typeof(StoreGeneratedPattern), item.Value.ToString())
        : System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreGeneratedPattern.None;
}
```